# I keep getting an error when in call displayMapData in main method

Tags: java

How should I write the code to call "displayMapData" in main method. I would really appreciate the help.

Would be helpful if you provided the code so I can learn from my mistakes.

```
package stormtroopers;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class StormTroopers
{

    public static double eucldeanDistance(double x2, double x1, double 2, double y1)
        {
            double d = 0;
            double xDif = Math.pow(x2-x1,2);
            double yDif = Math.pow(y2-y1,2);
            d = Math.sqrt(xDif + yDif);
            return d;
        }
    public static String distanceBetweenLocations(double x, double y, double [][] locations)
        {
            String s = "\t";
            double totalDistance = 0;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            for(int i=0; i < locations.length; i++)
                {
                    double d = eucldeanDistance(x,locations[i][0],y,locations[i][1]);
                    totalDistance += d;
                    s = s + df.format(d) + "\t";
                }
            return s + df.format(totalDistance);
        }
    public static void displayMapData(double[][] locations,String author)
        {
            System.out.println("___________________STORMTROOPER DISTANCE DATA____________________");
            System.out.println("\tST-1\t" + "\tST-2\t" + "\tST-1\t" + "\tST-4\t" + "\tST-5\t" + "\tST-6\t" + "\tST-7\t" + "\tST-8\t" + "\tST-9\t" + "\tST-10\t" + "TOTAL DISTANCE");
            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
                 {
                      String s = distanceBetreenLocations(locations[i][0],locations[i][1],locations);
                      System.out.println("ST-" + (i + 1) + s);
                      System.out.println();
                 }
            System.out.println("REPORT DATA CREATED BY " + author + "______________________");
        }
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println(displayMapData(double[][] locations,String author);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you improve your question? For example, show the source code.

Comment: a few things you need to change, in the main method, you don't define the procedure again. here you need defined paramaters for location and author. Second you dont need to call displayMapaData() in System.out.println since displayMapData returns void.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the main method?

Comment: "I uploaded a screenshot image of the code" please don't do that. Some of us are behind corporate networks that block imgur.com and won't be able to see your code, and nobody wants to have to transcribe the code from the image in order to test it when it could have been copy/pasted instead.

Comment: Where are the variables "locations" and "author" coming from?

Comment: Please stop doing this: putting up your homework and going "please complete or fix it". If you continue to put up such low quality input you might be banned from asking questions sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your call in `main` to `displayMapData()` should be an actualy call, and *isn't* a method declaration, it should have data (a 2D array of doubles, and a String) instead of variable declarations.

Something like:

```
double[][] data = {{0.5, 5.8, 2.3},
                   {5.2, 3.4, 0.0},
                   {1.2, 1.6, 2.0}};
System.out.println(displayMapData(data, "Me");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this, it will work,
You might want to do spacing between answers and change your name

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    public class StormTrooper {

    public static double euclideanDistance(double x2, double x1, double y2, double y1){
    double d = 0; 
    double xDif = Math.pow(x2-x1,2);
    double yDif = Math.pow(y2-y1,2);
    d = Math.sqrt(xDif + yDif);
    return d;
    }

    public static String distanceBetweenLocations (double x, double y, double[][] locations){
    String s = "\t";
    double totalDistance = 0; 
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
        double d = euclideanDistance(x,locations[i][0],y,locations[i][1]);
        totalDistance += d; 
        s = s + df.format(d) + "\t";
    }
    return s + df.format (totalDistance); 
    }

    public static void displayMapData(double[][] locations, String author){
    System.out.println("________________________STORMTROOPER DISTANCE DATA_____________________________");
    System.out.println("\tST-1\t" + "\tST-2\t" +"\tST-3\t" +"\tST-4\t" +"\tST-5\t" +"\tST-6\t" 
    +"\tST-7\t" 
                        + "\tST-8\t" +"\tST-9\t" +"\tST-10\t" + "TOTAL DISTANCE");
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
        String s = distanceBetweenLocations(locations[i][0], locations[i][1], locations);
        System.out.println("ST-" + (i + 1) + s); 
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("REPORN DATA CREATE BY" + author + 
    "_____________________________________________");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double[][] inputs = { { 32, 16 }, { 32, 14 }, { 33, 13 }, {35, 13}, { 36, 13 }, { 37, 15 }, {36 ,16}, {35 ,16.5}, {34 ,15}, { 33,16 }};
        String author = "Mayank";
        displayMapData(inputs, author);
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It was happening because you were calling map data using System.out.println(), which expects string and your function does not return any string. Go through code, you will get it